# Destructuring props in the function parameters using TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to my component library to use TypeScript and am attempting to convert a stateless functional component in React from ES6/JavaScript to TypeScript. I am wondering how I can avoid duplicating myself while still being able to deconstruct props outside the function while passing it parameters.

My component currently looks like this:

```
const allowedColors = {
  warning: "fa fa-exclamation",
  info: "fa fa-info",
  success: "fa fa-check",
  danger: "fa fa-minus-circle"
};

const AlertIcon = ({ className, color, ...props }) => (
  <FontAwesomeIcon
    {...props}
    iconClassName={allowedColors[color]}
    className={classNames(`alert-icon-${color}`, className)}
    aria-hidden="true"
    data-ut="alert-icon"
  />
);

AlertIcon.propTypes = {
  className: PropTypes.string,
  color: PropTypes.oneOf(Object.keys(allowedColors)).isRequired
};
```

How would I go about refactoring this into TypeScript?

Answer (score 95, accepted):

```
type Color = "warning" | 'info'| 'success' | 'danger'

interface IProps {
  color: Color
}

const AlertIcon = ({ className, color, ...props }: IProps) => { ... }
```

now when you use `AlertIcon` the `color` prop must be of type `Color`

to account for passing HTML attributes, like `className` you can do this:

```
interface IProps extends HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement> { ... }
```

where `HTMLElement` is your type of element.

Comment: Need to add `[x: string]: any` to your `IProps`

Comment: error. see: http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=type%20Color%20%3D%20%22warning%22%20%7C%20'info'%20%7C%20'success'%20%7C%20'danger'%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20IProps%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20color%3A%20Color%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20AlertIcon%20%3D%20(%7B%20className%2C%20color%2C%20...props%20%7D%3A%20IProps)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%20%7D

Comment: there's a better way to achieve that. see my edit. in anyway, your suggestion enables passing undeclared props which is not very type-safe.

Comment: And in your suggestion, I would implement the color to className mapping as a method inside the component?

Comment: yes, once you get the color name, mapping is up to you. what you did before will work.

Comment: Also, nicely explained here: https://medium.com/@rileyhilliard/es6-destructuring-in-typescript-4c048a8e9e15