# ERROR exercises.slice is not a function TypeError: exercises.slice is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, array-map

I am building an exercise website using react js but I am having issues with .slice() function. It is giving error that exercises.slice is not the function which is comming from props

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Pagination from "@mui/material/Pagination";
import { Box, Stack, Typography } from "@mui/material";

import { exerciseOptions, fetchData } from "../utils/fetchData";
import ExerciseCard from "./ExcerciseCard";

const Exercises = ({ exercises, setExercises, bodyPart }) => {
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);
  const [exercisesPerPage] = useState(6);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchExercisesData = async () => {
      let exercisesData = [];

      if (bodyPart === "all") {
        exercisesData = await fetchData(
          "https://exercisedb.p.rapidapi.com/exercises",
          exerciseOptions
        );
      } else {
        exercisesData = await fetchData(
          `https://exercisedb.p.rapidapi.com/exercises/bodyPart/${bodyPart}`,
          exerciseOptions
        );
      }

      setExercises(exercisesData);
    };

    fetchExercisesData();
  }, [bodyPart]);

  // Pagination
  const indexOfLastExercise = currentPage * exercisesPerPage;
  const indexOfFirstExercise = indexOfLastExercise - exercisesPerPage;
  const currentExercises = exercises.slice(
    indexOfFirstExercise,
    indexOfLastExercise
  )

  const paginate = (event, value) => {
    setCurrentPage(value);

    window.scrollTo({ top: 1800, behavior: "smooth" });
  };

  return (
    <Box id="exercises" sx={{ mt: { lg: "109px" } }} mt="50px" p="20px">
      <Typography
        variant="h4"
        fontWeight="bold"
        sx={{ fontSize: { lg: "44px", xs: "30px" } }}
        mb="46px"
      >
        Showing Results
      </Typography>
      <Stack
        direction="row"
        sx={{ gap: { lg: "107px", xs: "50px" } }}
        flexWrap="wrap"
        justifyContent="center"
      >
        {currentExercises.map((exercise, idx) => (
          <ExerciseCard key={idx} exercise={exercise} />
        ))}
      </Stack>
      <Stack sx={{ mt: { lg: "114px", xs: "70px" } }} alignItems="center">
        {exercises.length > 9 && (
          <Pagination
            color="standard"
            shape="rounded"
            defaultPage={1}
            count={Math.ceil(exercises.length / exercisesPerPage)}
            page={currentPage}
            onChange={paginate}
            size="large"
          />
        )}
      </Stack>
    </Box>
  );
};

export default Exercises;
```

Here's the code of exercises.jsx file

I tried converting it to toString but it didn't helped and giving same error [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z7PlJ.png)

Comment: In some jsx file you have `<Exercises exercises=something >`. The problem reported by this error is that `something` is not an array.

Comment: in home i have <Exercises
        setExercises={setExercises}
        exercises={exercises}
        bodyPart={bodyPart}
      />

Answer (score 0):

Destructuring the props like this is causing the issue. 'exercises' have type 'any' and you can not call '.slice()' on 'any'. It needs to be an array or a string. You need to set the type of the 'exercises'.

You can do something like this:

```
const Exercises = (props:any) => {
    const exercises:string[] = props.exercises;
    const currentExercises = exercises.slice(indexOfFirstExercise,indexOfLastExercise)

    return (
        <>
            <h1>Hello</h1>
        </>
    );
};
```

Or you can use the interface to solve this issue. Here is a good answer: [Destructuring props in the function parameters using TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52600056/destructuring-props-in-the-function-parameters-using-typescript)

Basically, you need to follow the TypeScript rules.